# clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-current_version 1'

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm using `ns-3` and write my code in `C++` in `Xcode`. In the terminal, it keeps giving me the error:

```
clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-compatibility_version 1'
clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-current_version 1'
clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
```

What are these errors supposed to mean?